# How to extract pdf data into excel?

Tags: excel, pdf, data-analysis

I want to convert pdf data into excel data. I have converted pdf to text file and have removed unnecessary text inside .txt file but they are now in rows but I want them to become columnwise.

PDF file: chemistry-chemists.com/chemister/Spravochniki/handbook-of-aqueous-solubility-data-2010.pdf

Current state of excel file :

[image]

Required state of excel file:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDFtables.com specialises in extracting tables from PDFs into Excel. This should be able to do what you are looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to Tabula a very efficient tool to convert table from pdf: https://github.com/tabulapdf/tabula

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET you can use that code by the way

```
    <div>
    Upload PDF File :<asp:FileUpload ID="fuPdfUpload" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnExportToExcel" Text="Export To Excel" OnClick="ExportToExcel" runat="server" />
</div>
```

!!You have to implement iTextSharp from NuGet!!

```
protected void ExportToExcel(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.fuPdfUpload.HasFile)
            {
                string file = Path.GetFullPath(fuPdfUpload.PostedFile.FileName);
                this.ExportPDFToExcel(file);
            }
        }

        private void ExportPDFToExcel(string fileName)
        {
            StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
            PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(fileName);

            for (int page = 1; page <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; page++)
            {
                ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new LocationTextExtractionStrategy();
                string currentText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, page, strategy);
                currentText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(currentText)));
                text.Append(currentText);

            }

            pdfReader.Close();
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=ReceiptExport.xls");
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            Response.Write(text);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
        }
```